# How to add a prefix ou suffix to files dowloaded via uGet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, downloads, uget

I've been using uGet to download files from sites for some days.

My question is simple :

Is there a way to add a prefix - suffix to files downloaded.

I noticed the field where you can specify a filename but this does not fulfill what I want to do.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Laurent06000

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify a prefix or suffix.  If you download a `.txt`, it should come in as a `.txt`.  If you specify `blahblah.img` in the filename, it will either come out `blahblah.img`, or `blahblah.img.txt`.

If you need to change it, you could run this in Terminal:

```
mv blahblah.txt blahblah.img
```

Or simply edit the filename in the GUI file browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel  but this does not anwer my question : it is at at the moment of the download that I'd like to change the name of the file being downloaded.

Comment: And what happens when you change it in the download filename window?

Comment: Obviously I can change the name of the saved file in the filename field, but this is NOT what I want to do. I'd like to add a suffix or prefix to the uGet saved file.